# Ajax preloader working only once

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, load

I have this script:

```
$(function() {
$(this).ajaxStart(function() {
$("#loading").show(); });
$(this).ajaxStop(function() {
$("#loading").hide(); });
});

$(document).ready(function() { 
$('.button').click(function () {
$("#contentDiv").load("content.php");
});

$('.button2').click(function () {
$("#contentDiv").load("content2.php");
});
});
```

And this html:

```
<div id="contentDiv">
<div id="loading"></div>

</div>
```

I want to show loading .gif before every new load, but now it works only first time whole page is loaded. So when I click first time "button", "loading" shows, "content" is loaded and "loading" hides. When I than click "button2", "content2" is loaded but "loading" did not shows. I try to take out "loading" div from "contentDiv", but than "loading" never hides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it working this way:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
$('.loading').show();
$('#contentDiv').hide();
}).ajaxStop(function() {
$('.loading').hide();
$('#contentDiv').show();
});
```

html:

```
<div id="contentDiv"></div>
<div class="loading"></div>
```

I have to made loading div class because ID was not working.

Answer (score 1):

write

```
<div id="loading" style="display:none"></div>
```

above the

```
<div id="contentDiv">
```

Answer (score 1):

You're replacing the content of `#contentDiv`, which contains the `#loading` div, so it may no longer exist after calling `.load()` if the div isn't also present in `content.php` or `content2.php`. It may appear as if your code works fully the first time, but rather than simply hiding `#loading` you're actually removing it entirely.

If that's not the problem, then it's possible that the AJAX calls complete quickly enough that the element is shown, and then hidden again, fast enough that you can't see it happen.

Comment: I think about it that way, and it is true because I am changing 3 divs using fade function and when the before opened div is shown, for a second is showing old content, and then new content, so loading is no more there. But it is not working when I implement it into content.php, when I put loading outside a div.... So maybe there is a different code which will work for me....

Answer (score 0):

An **ID** is meant to be a single unique instance on your page. On the other hand a **Class** can be reused multiple times. So really the following change alone should work:

`<div class="loading"></div>`